# Should we talk British or American round these parts?

Tags: discussion, tags

I got a little confused earlier today when I tried to tag a question as [maneuver](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maneuver) and discovered that there was no such tag in the system.  There was, however, a tag called [manoeuvre](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manoeuvre).

*"That can't be right"*, I remarked to my [pet bald eagle, who was perched atop a stack of NASCAR memorabilia and high-powered firearms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMkYT.jpg).  *"I'd better ask on Meta about this."*

**Should we use the tag manoeuvre or maneuver?**

Comment: i got re-edited last week when I changed centred to centered because I thought the first was a typo, not brit

Comment: The answer is that we should all speak Canadian, obviously. Eh.

Comment: We should talk either, but add tag synonyms for spelling variations

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changed to [maneuver](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maneuver) with a tag synonym of [manoeuvre](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manoeuvre).

Answer (score 7):

Good question, and one that's been discussed [many times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=british%20american%20english) before on meta.SE. The [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us) there (from SE's community manager) is that tags are in US English, anything else is whatever the poster uses and shouldn't be changed. In the specific case of manoeuvres, or any other reasonably common tag that differs in US and British English, I suppose a synonym would be a practical solution.

So score 1 for bald eagles.